# MVC - How to develop a wizard like control functionality in ajax

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I thought I would ask here about how to develop a wiazrd like control
in ajax for MVC before I started it.

The control will have pages that have data entry controls and 
on each page submission insert data into a database.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a JavaScript library? I know dojo has a wizard in dojox namespace, and I'm pretty sure there are wizards for jquery. If not, I'd do a wizard just like I would tabs, without the tab bar, and each view contains a form and next, previous, cancel and or restart buttons, all of which would handle the ajax calls/state management and change the view.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a wizard you probably actually should use separate web pages rather than having a single page that's updated through ajax calls, that way the forward and back buttons can work as nature intended in the browser for moving forward and back through the wizard.

Of course you can use fragment tricks to get forward / back working in a single page but in my experience this is tricky.